# Adding SQL record on local database via Java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, xampp

Edit: SOLVED, email address was too long while entering new record - expanding the  number of characters on DB solved the issue.

Basic question, but i'm struggling with adding simple sql record via java form into local database.
Here is sample of my DB:
[image: Database sample]

This is form created in NetBeans:

[image: adding new record form]

And this is my code when i click "Save" button after filling up the data

```
private void jbtnzapiszpracActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try
    {
       
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bazadanych","root","");
    String queryP = ("INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+email+"','"+gender+"','"+ip_address+"');");
    //Example:
    //INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES ('6','Marek','Marecki','m.m@gmail.comn','Male','0.000.00.0');
    
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(queryP);
    pst.setString(1, id.getText());
    pst.setString(2, first_name.getText());
    pst.setString(3, last_name.getText());
    pst.setString(4, email.getText());
    if (jrdM.isSelected())
    {
        gender = "Male";
    }
     if (jrdK.isSelected())
    {
        gender = "Female";
    }
     pst.setString(5, gender);
     pst.setString(6,ip_address.getText());
     pst.executeUpdate();
     
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    
    }
  this.setVisible(false);
  
}
```

I'm pretty sure the connection to database is established as in different form i can preview it all, but the sql database is not updateing with new records when i press "Save"

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error message?

Comment: No errors - it's just not adding any records to database after pressing "Save"

Comment: Are you sure? No exception? Your catch block is empty (You should never do that) Please add the exception output to the question.

Comment: You are using PreparedStatement     String queryP = ("INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+email+"','"+gender+"','"+ip_address+"');");

then why are you concatenating the values here , it should be replaced with '?'

Comment: I tried changing query statement into:
        String queryP = "INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

reg. Excpetion - how do i do that (my apologies, i'm pretty new in Java)

Comment: You can wrap the exception in a runtime exception and throw it like this: `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` But this is just for testing. check out [Handling Exceptions Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) to learn more.

Comment: Lupz - thank you so much - NetBeans sent me an error - Data too long for column "email".

Now it works 100% fine, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear that you found a solution! Does it work with your original query string?

Comment: Yep, all works perfectly - with your and Hermandsheep's query of course! Cheers! ;)

Comment: additional points, it would be really nice if add some validation before inserting the data directly, also to be more specific it will throw `SQLException` , also it would be good practice If you close your `prepared statements` and `connection`, also `pst.executeUpdate();` will return number of affected rows, lastly, you have to make sure weather id already exists or not to prevent `SQLException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**INFO**

> There was another issue with the length of data. Logging the exceptions was the key to see what was going on. See comments.

---

There are no placeholders in your query template string.

Instead of

```
String queryP = ("INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES ('"+id+"','"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+email+"','"+gender+"','"+ip_address+"');");
```

Use

```
String queryP = "INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";
```

(I'm not sure if you need the single quotes here)

Comment: I changed it into:
String queryP = "INSERT INTO pracownicy (id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);";

It didn't help tho.